# Looping through nested Dictionaries in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

i want to get the dynamic keys from this dictionary but i'm getting an error when i loop it.

```
d= {
    "name": "rex"
    "age": "23"
     "data": {
                "country" :   { "name": "xx", "loc": "ee" , "loc1": "pp" }
                 "country2" : { "name": "tx", "loc": "ef" , "loc2": "rp" }
                 "country2"  :{ "name": "yx", "loc": "ve" , "loc1": "hp" }
              }
   }
```

I'm trying to parse these info into a neat csv. But this is not looping through the dictionary and stopping abruptly. How to loop concisely through the dictionary catching all the nested values

```
name= d["name"]
  age= d["age"]
  for i in d["data"]:
      country_name= d[i]["name"]
      country_loc= d[i]["loc"]
      country_loc1 = d[i]["loc1"]
```

Comment: `i` is itself a dictionary. Your lines should be like `country_name = i["name"]`.

Comment: pay attention that your dictionary string_like not formatted well, as long as it missed `,` in between instances of key:value pairs. for example after `"rex"` and after `"country" :   { "name": "xx", "loc": "ee" , "loc1": "pp" }`

Comment: It's a bit unclear what output you want, but if you want to get into tabular format and output to csv, then pandas is pretty optimal for that (see answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use

```
name = d["name"]
age = d["age"]
for i in d["data"]:
    country_name = d["data"][i]["name"]
    #                ^^^
    country_loc = d["data"][i]["loc"]
    country_loc1 = d["data"][i]["loc1"]

    print(country_name)
```

Or - considered "more pythonic":

```
for _, country in d["data"].items():
    print(country["name"])
```

Comment: Use `i["name"]` instead of `d["data"][i]["name"]`

Comment: @zvi: Nah. Use the second approach altogether.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get to a CSV, a simple approach is to leverage the power of pandas. There are various approaches, but one is the below:

```
import pandas as pd

#create data
d= {
   "name": "rex"
   "age": "23"
   "data": {
       "country" :   { "name": "xx", "loc": "ee" , "loc1": "pp" }
       "country2" : { "name": "tx", "loc": "ef" , "loc2": "rp" }
       "country2" :{ "name": "yx", "loc": "ve" , "loc1": "hp" }
   }
   }

# we reset index so that concatenated objects share an index
df = pd.DataFrame(d).reset_index() 
# json_normalise expands our nested data. Concat unions along the rows. We drop the now unneeded data column
out = pd.concat([df,pd.json_normalize(df.data)],axis=1).drop('data',axis=1)
out.to_csv('out.csv')
```

Looks like:

```
      index name age name loc loc1
0   country  rex  23   xx  ee   pp
1  country2  rex  23   yx  ve   hp
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is a version of the code that works. I suggest to compare it to the original code and to try to understand the differences:

```
d = {"name": "rex",
     "age": "23",
     "data": {
              "country": {"name": "xx", "loc": "ee", "loc1": "pp"},
              "country2": {"name": "tx", "loc": "ef", "loc1": "rp"},
              "country3": {"name": "yx", "loc": "ve", "loc1": "hp"}
             }
     }

name = d["name"]
age = d["age"]
for i in d["data"].keys():
    country_name = d["data"][i]["name"]
    country_loc = d["data"][i]["loc"]
    country_loc1 = d["data"][i]["loc1"]
```

Comment: This is one to one copy of a former answer - just three minutes later.